# Makefile rule to create several files, that each depend on different targets

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile that does some file aggregation. Something like the following: I have data for several days about what I ate for breakfast lunch and dinner. Files are named something like:

```
monday_breakfast.meal
monday_lunch.meal
monday_dinner.meal
tuesday_breakfast.meal
...
```

or if working with numbers makes it simpler:

```
00_00.meal
00_11.meal
00_22.meal
11_00.meal
...
```

The objective is to aggregate the three files for each day into a single file for each day, but do this for all days. Is it possible to write a rule that does this? The tricky part is I don't know how many days worth of files there will be when I run make, so I want it to be generic.

I was thinking something like:

```
DAYS= $(sort $(patsubst _*,,*.meal))
day: %.day: $(DAYS):
```

But then I get stuck. I am using this as a sort of exercise to learn more about Makefiles---it seemed like it would be easy at first but I can not think this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make's ability to manipulate strings is not all that one might desire. But here goes.

Suppose we have:

```
monday_breakfast.meal
monday_lunch.meal
monday_dinner.meal
tuesday_breakfast.meal
tuesday_lunch.meal
tuesday_dinner.meal
wednesday_breakfast.meal
```

First, get the names of all the `meal` files:

```
MEALS := $(wildcard *.meal)
```

Then somehow we want to reduce this list to the names of the days. If we take *one* filename:

```
FIRSTMEAL := monday_breakfast.meal
```

We can split it by turning the underscore into a space, then grab the first fragment:

```
FRAGS := $(subst _, , $(FIRSTMEAL))  #  monday breakfast.meal
FIRSTDAY := $(word 1, $(FRAGS))      #  monday
```

So we can do this for all meals:

```
DAYS := $(sort $(foreach x,$(MEALS), $(word 1,$(subst _, ,$(x)))))
```

(The `sort` removes the repetitions in the list.)

Now that we have `DAYS` ("monday tuesday wednesday"), we want to write a rule or rules to do the aggregation. How easy this will be depends on exactly what kind of aggregation you mean, what tool you'll use, and whether it accepts wildcards.